# How enable gzip compression middleware in go-chi

Tags: http, go, gzip, go-chi

How can I enable gzip compression using the gzip middleware of the go-chi framework?

Try using the example shown here:

https://github.com/go-chi/chi/issues/204

but when I check with curl, I get this:

```
$ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I http://127.0.0.1:3333
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2019 19:06:39 GMT
```

I tried the code "hello world":

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    //r.Use(middleware.DefaultCompress) //using this produces the same result
    r.Use(middleware.Compress(5, "gzip"))
    r.Get("/", Hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
}

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html") //according to the documentation this must be here to enable gzip
    w.Write([]byte("hello world\n"))
}
```

but when I try to verify with curl, the result is the same

```
$ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I http://127.0.0.1:3333
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2019 19:06:39 GMT
```

what's going on?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with gzip at all. You're issuing a HEAD request, but your server doesn't accept HEAD, it expects GET.

Comment: Also, issuing HEAD instead of GET when you want a compressed response body makes no sense since HEAD has no response body at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, now I understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the commented `middleware.DefaultCompress` and a normal `GET` request.

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.DefaultCompress)
    r.Get("/", Hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
}

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.Write([]byte("hello world\n"))
}
```

Try with `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -v http://localhost:3333 --compressed
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3333/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3333 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3333
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2019 23:37:52 GMT
< Content-Length: 36
<
hello world
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Or `HTTPie`:

```sh
$ http :3333
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2019 23:38:31 GMT

hello world
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, use @Mikel Pascual answer

Answer (score 14):

The other answers are outdated now. I had to solve this myself, so here what I found out.

Your error is here:

```golang
r.Use(middleware.Compress(5, "gzip"))
```

The second argument ("types") refers to the content types that the compression will be applied to. For example: `"text/html"`, `"application/json"`, etc

Just add a list of the content-types you want to compress, or remove the argument altogether:

```golang
func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Compress(5))
    r.Get("/", Hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
}
```

This will compress all the content-types defined in the default list from [middleware.Compress](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/middleware/compress.go):

```golang
var defaultCompressibleContentTypes = []string{
    "text/html",
    "text/css",
    "text/plain",
    "text/javascript",
    "application/javascript",
    "application/x-javascript",
    "application/json",
    "application/atom+xml",
    "application/rss+xml",
    "image/svg+xml",
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

`r.Use(middleware.DefaultCompress)` has now been marked as `DEPRECATED`.

To enable compression you need to create a compressor, and use its handler.

```
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
r.Use(middleware.Logger)

compressor := middleware.NewCompressor(flate.DefaultCompression)
r.Use(compressor.Handler())

r.Get("/", Hello)
http.ListenAndServe(":3333", r)
```

The `flate` package must be imported as `compress/flate`.

Comment: Thanks. To me, no "()" for "Handler":
```
compressor := middleware.NewCompressor(flate.DefaultCompression)
r.Use(compressor.Handler)
```